# Band pass filter not filtering?

Tags: passive-filter, band-pass, filtering

[image]I am putting together this band pass filter for a guitar project but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the diagram and the breadboard I'm working with. There is a button there that isn't doing anything right now.

Bpf https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suysz.jpg

The band range should be from 400-800ish but the signal is still passing above and below these frequencies.

A pulse generator is inputting the signal. Through the filter into an oscilloscope (for testing)

Please advise.

Comment: @Alexander Actually, it would be better to use the schematic editing tool (in the toolbar at the top of the editing window) if you can. The easier it is to read, the better.

Answer (score 1):

You may be expecting too much from this simple filter. The circuit is a mild bandpass that will attenuate (but certainly not eliminate - no filter will do that) signals around 600 Hz:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. How would I make it stronger? Op-amp?

Comment: Your simple (first order) highpass and lowpass RC filters produce gradual frequency slopes. You need more orders (3rd and 4th orders) for steeper slopes and sharper corners. Most people use Sallen-Key filters made with opamps.

Comment: Ah, thanks homie. Do you have a good tutorial for making 3rd and 4th order filters?

Comment: @Alexander There are good sites that will design them for you. If you know what to ask for and know how to interpret what they present: see [here](https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/). But if you can't interpret things, then that's another thing. For example, your bandpass width and center present a factor of \$\frac12\sqrt{2}\$ or about 0.71. This is right at the cusp of whether it is better to use a low-pass and high-pass separately designed and then combined together vs a more holistic design that combines them for fewer parts for the performance.

Comment: @Alexander Write out your specifications. What frequencies ***must*** be stopped, for example, and by how much? (Nothing is perfect, so you must accept something even where you don't want it. It just needs to remove enough for your purposes.)

Comment: @Alexander [Here's what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKrlq.png) by way of example. The *brick wall* version isn't possible. But the *4th order Cheby* is. If you are just looking for a passive component design, then you need to call that out. If you are open to an active filter, then you must also call that out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fff4q5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply KCL, we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply Ohm's law, we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Solving for the transfer function gives:

$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag4$$

We can can set \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$, \$\displaystyle\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\$.

So, the complex transfer function becomes:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)+\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+1\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\text{C}_1}\cdot\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+1\right)+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{C}_2+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_3+\text{C}_1\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2^2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\omega\text{j}+\text{C}_2-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2^2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2+\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}

Now, we want to solve for the value that \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\$ is at a maximum:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=\dots\tag6$$

Solving this gives:

$$\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\tag7$$

At the maximum, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag8$$

So, the cut-off frequency can be solved:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\dots\tag9$$

Which gives:

$$\omega_\pm=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)^2}\pm\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)}\tag{10}$$

So, the bandwidth is given by:

$$\mathcal{B}:=\left|\omega_+-\omega_-\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}\tag{11}$$

And the quality factor is given by:

$$\mathcal{Q}:=\frac{\hat{\omega}}{\mathcal{B}}=\frac{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag{12}$$

Using your values, we find:

- $$\hat{\omega}=625000 \sqrt{\frac{2}{61721}}\approx3557.78\space\text{rad/sec}\tag{13}$$
- $$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{19910}{35441}\approx0.561779\tag{14}$$
- $$\omega_+=\frac{15625 \left(\sqrt{2046093281}+35441\right)}{123442}\approx10211.6\space\text{rad/sec}\tag{15}$$
- $$\omega_-=\frac{15625 \left(\sqrt{2046093281}-35441\right)}{123442}\approx1239.55\space\text{rad/sec}\tag{16}$$
- $$\mathcal{B}=\frac{553765625}{61721}\approx8972.08\space\text{rad/sec}\tag{17}$$
- $$\mathcal{Q}=\frac{40 \sqrt{123442}}{35441}\approx0.396539\tag{18}$$

---

**Edit**, we can see that the absolute value of your transfer function is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\text{j}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)+\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\text{j}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{C}_2\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\text{C}_2\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag{19}
\end{equation}

And the argument is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}-0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta=0\\
\\
0&\space\text{if}\space\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space0<\omega<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\omega>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega}{1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2}\right)&\space\text{if}\space0<\omega<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2-1}{\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\omega>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}}
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag{20}
\end{equation}

Where \$\alpha:=1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\omega^2\$ and \$\beta:=\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_2+\text{C}_2\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\omega\$.